# How to join MySQL tables in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, mariadb

I am very new to rails and working with databases in general. I am trying simply display a list of all of the residence_staff members who are 'managers' and the hallName of the hallOfResidence that they work in. residence_staff is 1 table with the field 'fName' and the name of the hall as a foreign key to the hallOfResidence table. How can I join the two tables and display it to the screen?

Currently I am only displaying a list of all of the residence_staff members.

**Staff model:**

```
class ResidenceStaff < ApplicationRecord
  validates :fName, presence: true

end
```

**Halls model:**

```
class HallOfResidence < ApplicationRecord
end
```

**Controller:**

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @residence_staff = ResidenceStaff.all
  end
end
```

**View**

```
<h1>Title</h1>

<div>
  <% @residence_staff.each do |residence_staff| %>
    <%= residence_staff.fName%>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: please refer http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joins

Comment: `name of the hall as a foreign key` - hm. That sounds bad. Also, `fName` is not conventional naming. How do you determine if a `ResidenceStaff` is a manager?

Comment: They have a field called position and some of them are 'manager'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caveat Emptor: Code Not Tested.

Given something like (you really should use `hall_of_residence_id` as the foreign key):

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: residence_staffs
#
#  id                                :integer          not null, primary key
#  first_name                        :string
#  hall_of_residence_id              :integer
#  position                          :string
#  created_at                        :datetime         not null
#  updated_at                        :datetime         not null
#
class ResidenceStaff < ApplicationRecord
  validates :first_name, presence: true
  belongs_to :hall_of_residence

  class << self

    def managers
      where(position: 'manager')
    end

  end
end
```

And:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: hall_of_residences
#
#  id                                :integer          not null, primary key
#  name                              :string
#  created_at                        :datetime         not null
#  updated_at                        :datetime         not null
#
class HallOfResidence < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :residence_staffs
end
```

It seems like you should be able to do something like (see the [Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) for information on `includes`):

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @residence_staffs = ResidenceStaff.all
    @residence_staff_managers = ResidenceStaff.managers.includes(:hall_of_residence)
  end

end
```

And:

```
<h1>Title</h1>

<div>
  <% @residence_staff_managers.each do |residence_staff| %>
    <%= residence_staff.first_name>
    <%= residence_staff.hall_of_residence.name >
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: I did change the residence halls table to have an int ID and everything works fine now except in the view residence_staff cannot identify the fName field. Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean, "cannot identify the fName field"? Are you getting an error? If so, add it to your question.

Comment: I am not getting an error on that just in the editor it is not identifying that fName is a field of the staff anymore. However when I run I get this error: "   Hall(hallId: integer, hallName: text, street: text, city: text, postcode: integer, phoneNumber: integer, sfaffNumber: integer) was not recognized for preload    "  I think there is something happening incorrectly with the DB migrations